# React Deployement Issue

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

I am deploying a react application , when i run the serve -s build command , my project loads but as i put it in apache server , i am only able to see the background color and nothing else . There is no error on the console and i can see the API's getting called in the network tab but still no component loads . I dont understand , if there is any issue in my react router .
THIS IS HOW I HAVE DONE ROUTING

```
<Router basename="/KDS">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        {localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") ? (
          <>
            <Route exact path="/AllOrders" component={AllOrders} />
            <Route exact path="/Waiting" component={Waiting} />
            <Route exact path="/Preparing" component={Preparing} />
            <Route exact path="/Ready" component={Ready} />
            <Route exact path="/Delivered" component={Delivered} />
            <Route exact path="/Cancelled" component={Cancelled} />
          </>
        ) : null}

        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Can you see at "Network" tab are your Javascript chunks loaded?

Comment: If you are hosting your react app in subdomain then please add the path in `homepage` in `package.json` else add `.` in `package.json`

Comment: I have added the homepage property in package.json , still I get the same issue

Comment: I am unable to see my css and js chunks in the network tab , although i feel that i have provided the correct path to them , as i am getting redirected to the files if i cntrl+click them on my visual studio .